# Hyperledger Fabric Images v1.4.4 Download Issue

Tags: github, hyperledger-fabric, pem

I am trying to download the latest images v1.4.4.But it returns the github's certificate issue.

```
===> Downloading version 1.4.4 platform specific fabric binaries
===> Downloading:  
 https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v1.4.4/hyperledger-fabric-linux-amd64-1.4.4.tar.gz
--2020-01-08 17:50:47--  
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v1.4.4/hyperledger-fabric-linux-amd64-1.4.4.tar.gz
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 13.234.176.102
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|13.234.176.102|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify github.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended 
Validation Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US’:
Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to github.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
tar (child): hyperledger-fabric-linux-amd64-1.4.4.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or 
directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
rm: cannot remove 'hyperledger-fabric-linux-amd64-1.4.4.tar.gz': No such file or directory
==> There was an error downloading the binary file.

 ------> 1.4.4 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download <----
```

As mentioned ,I have tried the methods to ignore certificate validation process using '-k'  && '-insecure' in Curl .But the same issue still persists.

How can I resolve this issue?Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I thought a problem in your `fabic-sample` path. First, you need to clone `fabric-samples` latest repository. After downloading, go to `fabric-samples` repository and run [image]

and for specific run [image].

Still, you face problems then remove old version images and containers of hyperledger fabric for this run `docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)` & then download particular fabric images.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Using the same u mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a problem with your ca store. Can you tell me which OS are you running, and the version please?

Assuming it is some flavour of Linux, please consider the following options

- Please make sure that the OS time is synced with the network (timezone is correct etc ). Retry the process
- Try this as root:

  update-ca-certificates -f

  Then retry the process. Hopefully it will work.
- One more option you have is, assuming that you have a desktop browser,  type the url [1.4.4 download link from the error message above](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v1.4.4/hyperledger-fabric-linux-amd64-1.4.4.tar.gz) into the browser (  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v1.4.4/hyperledger-fabric-linux-amd64-1.4.4.tar.gz )
  And  download it manually. Extract it and execute the script manually.